# RegEx for replacing a specific word

Tags: javascript, css, regex, regex-group

I'm trying to change background color one specific word to use regexp but i dont know how i write this code in javascript

I try to write some code javascript but it did not work

```
let test = RegExp(/\bjavascript/ig).css('background-color' 'blue');
```

I reload page but it does not work.

Comment: Do you mean to change the background color of an html element? Why do you want to use regex?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that we'd like to capture and change a color in CSS formats, which we can do so using an expression similar to:

```
(background(-color)?):\s+(.+?)(\s+)?;
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/oYCmhJ/1/)

or:

```
(background-color):\s+(.+?)(\s+)?;
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/4XsCxV/1/)

#### Test

```js
const regex = /(background(-color)?):\s+(.+?)(\s+)?;/gmi;
const str = `background-color: blue;
background: green;
background: green ;
background: green ;`;
const subst = `$1:yellow;`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]